# Next JS: Console Logs in getStaticProps async function call

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, next.js

### Problem

Trying to log the return of an async function that is being called within a function that is being invoked by `getStaticProps`.

**Code**

```js
// pages/foo/index.js

import { getFoos } from '../../utils';


export async function getStaticProps() { 
  const foos = await getFoos();
  
  return { props: { foos } }; 
}

export default function Foos({ foos }) { 
 return ( 
  <div>
   {* foos *}
  </div>
 )
}
```

```js
// utils/index.js

export async function getFooNames() { 
 // do something

 return something; 
}

export async function getFoos() { 
  const fooNames = await getFooNames();

  console.log(fooNames); // <-- logs nothing

  const foos = [{ name: "hello", place: "world"}] // <-- some array of foos, not important

  return [...fooNames, ...foos]; // <-- getStaticProps is able to return this and assign to props just fine
}
```

#### What I Tried

- Changed the `console.log` to `console.warn`
- Changed the `const fooNames = await getFooNames();` to a promise chain:

```js
getFooNames().then(response => console.log(response));
```

- Console logged the await function instead of assigning to a variable: `console.log(await getFooNames());`

Nothing logged in any case. I thought maybe it wasn't logging because it was failing silently but if that were the case then the `getStaticProps` wouldn't have data in it right?

#### Question

How can I log data in an async function being invoked by `getStaticProps`?

Comment: `getStaticProps` is executed server side. Did you look at the logging result on the terminal where you did your build ?

Comment: Yes it was logging in the terminal. I realized that a little after I made the post . I was losing my mind. Thank you @RomanMkrtchian. Should I delete this question or turn it into a Q/A style question?

Comment: You can change the content, but I don't think you should delete. If you had this problem, other people might have it too ;)

Comment: I had this question, thank you for not deleting it! I had run `npm run dev` (i.e., `next dev`) and it wasn't showing me any printouts. When I killed next and reran `npm run dev`, the console output appeared 